# "Your request produced an error [new nullrespone]" occured while performing in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

During in-app-purchase, when I change my store, then iTunes, Apple store showing me the error like:

> Your request produced an error [new null response ]

Why this error is occurring not Always but sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Looks like a bug, like you can't change store for in-app purchase. Try signing in to the "correct" store before attempting to make your in-app purchase.